# Shredding XML column in SQL Server into new tables

Tags: sql-server, xml, shred

I have a source table, each row of which has an XML field that contains an unknown number of survey responses that I need to shred and put into output tables. I've tried nodes and OPENXML and I can't seem to get it working. From my research, I'm thinking I need to use CROSS APPLY, but I can't seem to put it all together in my head in a way that I understand and get it to work. I apologize if I'm missing something simple, but I really am stuck and would appreciate any help offered for how to deal with this.

Here's the source table containing imported data (the format of which I have no control over) that looks like this:

```
ImportId    SurveyId    DateImported              ResponseData
--------    --------    ------------              ------------
1           11223344    2017-05-21 18:00:00.00    <survey><data><result>...
2           55667788    2017-05-21 18:01:00.00    <survey><data><result>...
3           99009988    2017-05-21 18:02:00.00    <survey><data><result>...
```

Here's a simplified example of the XML in the ResponseData column:

```
<survey>
    <data>
        <result>
            <id>12345</id>
            <date_submitted>2017-05-10 09:30:15</date_submitted>
            <url_variables>
                <respondent_id>
                    <key>respondent_id</key>
                    <value>987654</value>
                    <type>url</type>
                </respondent_id>
                <respondent_level>
                    <key>respondent_level</key>
                    <value>5</value>
                    <type>url</type>
                </respondent_level>
            </url_variables>
            <survey_data>
                <question>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <answer>Yes</answer>
                </question>
                <question>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <answer>No</answer>
                </question>
                <question>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <subquestions>
                        <subquestion>
                            <id>4</id>                           
                            <answer>Maybe</answer>
                        </subquestion>
                        <subquestion>
                            <id>5</id>                           
                            <answer>I don't know</answer>
                        </subquestion>
                    </subquestions>
                </question>
                ... more questions ...
            </survey_data>
        </result>
        <result>
            <id>67890</id>
            <date_submitted>2017-05-11 10:00:00</date_submitted>
            <url_variables>
                <respondent_id>
                    <key>respondent_id</key>
                    <value>34567</value>
                    <type>url</type>
                </respondent_id>
                <respondent_level>
                    <key>respondent_level</key>
                    <value>10</value>
                    <type>url</type>
                </respondent_level>
            </url_variables>
            <survey_data>
                <question>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <answer>No</answer>
                </question>
                <question>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <answer>Yes</answer>
                </question>
                <question>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <subquestions>
                        <subquestion>
                            <id>4</id>                           
                            <answer>Definitely not</answer>
                        </subquestion>
                        <subquestion>
                            <id>5</id>                           
                            <answer>I object</answer>
                        </subquestion>
                    </subquestions>
                </question>
                ... more questions ...
            </survey_data>
        </result>
        ... more results ...
    <data>
</survey>
```

I need to take this data, shredding the XML to get multiple results in each ResponseData field and put it in two tables like these:

```
ResultId    SurveyId    RespondentId    RespondentLevel    DateSubmitted
--------    --------    ------------    ---------------    -------------
12345       11223344    987654          5                  2017-05-10 09:30:15
67890       11223344    34567           10                 2017-05-11 10:00:00
... 
(Data extracted from the rest of ImportId 1 followed by ImportId 2, 3, etc)

ResultId      QuestionId    SubquestionId    Answer
----------    ----------    -------------    ------
12345         1             0                Yes
12345         2             0                No
12345         3             4                Maybe
12345         3             5                I don't know
67890         1             0                No
67890         2             0                Yes
67890         3             4                Definitely not
67890         3             5                I object
 ... 
(Data extracted from the rest of ImportId 1 followed by ImportId 2, 3, etc)
```

Comment: Maybe you can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931604/t-sql-convert-xml-field-to-multi-column-dataset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Two Tables, you would need two queries

**Example  (I used only 1 record but will apply to multiple)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ImportId] int,[SurveyId] int,[DateImported] datetime,[ResponseData] xml)
Insert Into @YourTable Values
(1,11223344,'2017-05-21 18:00:00.00','<survey><data><result><id>12345</id><date_submitted>2017-05-10 09:30:15</date_submitted><url_variables><respondent_id><key>respondent_id</key><value>987654</value><type>url</type></respondent_id><respondent_level><key>respondent_level</key><value>5</value><type>url</type></respondent_level></url_variables><survey_data><question><id>1</id><answer>Yes</answer></question><question><id>2</id><answer>No</answer></question><question><id>3</id><subquestions><subquestion><id>4</id><answer>Maybe</answer></subquestion><subquestion><id>5</id><answer>I don''t know</answer></subquestion></subquestions></question></survey_data></result><result><id>67890</id><date_submitted>2017-05-11 10:00:00</date_submitted><url_variables><respondent_id><key>respondent_id</key><value>34567</value><type>url</type></respondent_id><respondent_level><key>respondent_level</key><value>10</value><type>url</type></respondent_level></url_variables><survey_data><question><id>1</id><answer>No</answer></question><question><id>2</id><answer>Yes</answer></question><question><id>3</id><subquestions><subquestion><id>4</id><answer>Definitely not</answer></subquestion><subquestion><id>5</id><answer>I object</answer></subquestion></subquestions></question></survey_data></result></data></survey>')

Select B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select [ResultID]        = r.n.value('(id)[1]','int')
                      ,A.[SurveyId]
                      ,[RespondentId]    = r.n.value('(url_variables/respondent_id/value)[1]','int')
                      ,[RespondentLevel] = r.n.value('(url_variables/respondent_level/value)[1]','int')
                      ,[DateSubmitted]   = r.n.value('(date_submitted)[1]','datetime')
                 From  A.[ResponseData].nodes('survey/data/result') r(n)
             ) B


Select B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select [ResultID]      = r.n.value('(id)[1]','int')
                      ,[QuestionId]    = IsNull(q.n.value('(id)[1]','int'),0)
                      ,[SubquestionId] = IsNull(s.n.value('(id)[1]','int'),0)
                      ,[answer]        = concat(q.n.value('(answer)[1]','varchar(50)') 
                                               ,s.n.value('(answer)[1]','varchar(50)') 
                                               )
                 From  A.[ResponseData].nodes('survey/data/result') r(n)
                 Cross Apply r.n.nodes('survey_data/question')      q(n)
                 Outer Apply q.n.nodes('subquestions/subquestion')  s(n)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much; you're a lifesaver.

Comment: @Sunny Happy to help